# Не пушатся файлы в гит

Tags: git, github

Папки и файлы не пушатся в гит, в чем может быть причина? Некоторые пушатся, некоторые нет. Те что не пушатся красные

[image: webstorm]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

добавь их, git add .
если у тебя jetbrains ide то в разделе vcs

Comment: Помогло, спасибо